# Bootstrap class alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use the bootstrap 4 card class with the following HTML code and output. However, I want the text in h5 to be beside the "Title" so that it is all one line. I'd also like the button to be appearing at the top right inline with the Title. I am bit new to styling so I always have trouble knowing when things will be inline or new line.

[image: Output]

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
        <h5>-  smaller that should be beside main title</h5>
        <button class="card-title btn btn-primary pull-right">Button</button>
        <p class="card-text">Entry 1</p>
        <p class="card-text">Entry 2</p>
        <p class="card-text">Entry 3</p>
        <p class="card-text">Entry 4</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `d-inline` class to display them as inline elements

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-block">
    <h4 class="card-title d-inline">Title</h4>
    <h5 class="d-inline">- smaller that should be beside main title</h5>
    <button class="card-title btn btn-primary pull-right">Button</button>
    <p class="card-text">Entry 1</p>
    <p class="card-text">Entry 2</p>
    <p class="card-text">Entry 3</p>
    <p class="card-text">Entry 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i didn't think with bootstrap class, you beat me up

Comment: @Naila I prefer just writing CSS, too! But if OP's using bootstrap, they should probably utilize the classes. Btw, your code moves the button up beside the headings.

Comment: @Naila oops! somehow missed that part.

Comment: Thanks guys. Why there a d-inline required for the button in this case?

Comment: @user172902 why "isn't" there a d-inline? I'm assuming that's your question. `.d-inline` makes something inline. But `.btn` is inline-block by default.

Answer (score 1):

Try this using put `pull-left` class

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title pull-left">Title</h4>
        <h5 class=" pull-left">-  smaller that should be beside main title</h5>
        <button class="card-title btn btn-primary pull-right">Button</button>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <p class="card-text">Entry 1</p>
        <p class="card-text">Entry 2</p>
        <p class="card-text">Entry 3</p>
        <p class="card-text">Entry 4</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

or you can done using `display:inline-block`

```css
.card .card-title,.card h5{ 
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
        <h5>-  smaller that should be beside main title</h5>
        <button class="card-title btn btn-primary pull-right">Button</button>       
        <p class="card-text">Entry 1</p>
        <p class="card-text">Entry 2</p>
        <p class="card-text">Entry 3</p>
        <p class="card-text">Entry 4</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply fix this with `inline-block`

```css
.card-title , h5{
   display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
        <h5>-  smaller that should be beside main title</h5>
        <button class="card-title btn btn-primary">Button</button>
        <p class="card-text">Entry 1</p>
        <p class="card-text">Entry 2</p>
        <p class="card-text">Entry 3</p>
        <p class="card-text">Entry 4</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to accomplish that.   [WORKING EXAMPLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/4afLr272/)

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-block">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <h5>-  smaller that should be beside main title</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
           <button class="card-title btn btn-primary pull-right">Button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
        <p class="card-text">Entry 1</p>
        <p class="card-text">Entry 2</p>
        <p class="card-text">Entry 3</p>
        <p class="card-text">Entry 4</p>
    </div>
</div>
```